# Javascript confirm & while looped echo

Tags: php, javascript, while-loop, confirm

I have a small problem, I made a delete button with a PHP while loop which looks like this:

```
while($something = mysql_fetch_array($sql_something)){

    $id = $something['id']
    echo '<a href="somewhere.php?id='.$id.'"><button onclick="delconfirm()">Delete</button></a>

}
```

this echo's a few delete buttons for some content. However I need user confirmation for deleting first, this is where `onclick="delconfirm()"` comes in.

my confirm looks like this:

```
function delconfirm()
{
    var r=confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this content?");

    if (r==true){

        // ...do nothing i guess? it needs to redirect using the PHP echo'd link...

    }
    else{

        window.location = "edit.php";

    }
}
```

However, whether you press cancel or ok, it'll delete it anyway. How can I fix this?

Comment: Note that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated (see the [red box](http://php.net/mysql_query)).

Comment: You have a `<button>` inside an `<a>`? That seems odd. How does your whole form look like?

Comment: `r==true` is a rather pointless use of `==`; `r` evaluated in boolean context should come up with the same result.  If you really need to compare exactly to `true` then use `r === true`.

Comment: You need to return something. onclick='return delconfirm();'> and then  return something from delconfirm();

Comment: Yeah is there a reason you have a `button` inside an `a`? I can't imagine a reason, even for styling purposes, to have them nested like that. Anyways, don't handle the `onclick` event with the `button` - handle everything with the `a` - the event will bubble up and you can prevent the `a`'s behavior (or not), depending on the `confirm`

Comment: And you probably shouldn't allow an updating operation (deleting) to be accessed with GET (`window.location`/`a.href`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
while($something = mysql_fetch_array($sql_something)){

    $id = $something['id']
    echo '<a href="somewhere.php?id='.$id.'"><button onclick="return delconfirm();">Delete</button></a>

}
```

And then your function:

```
function delconfirm()
{
    return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this content?");
}
```

**EDIT**: If you want a more **[unobtrusive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)** solution:

```
while($something = mysql_fetch_array($sql_something)){

    $id = $something['id']
    echo '<input type="button" value="Delete" data-id="$id" />';

}
```

And then some javascript to bind the event:

```
function bindButtons() {
    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        if (buttons[i].type == "button") {
            buttons[i].onclick = function () {
                location.href='somewhere.php?id=' + this.getAttribute("data-id");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and bind it to the `window.onload`, as per Ian suggestion:

```
window.onload = bindButtons;
```

**Note**: If you were using jQuery this solution would be easier and more elegant.

[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3tHXv/)

Comment: @MarcelKorpel I think technically `return false` from an inline `onclick` handler will stop propagation, therefore not even letting the `<a>` know that anything was clicked...therefore working

Comment: Nice unobtrusive suggestion :) Maybe instead of `<body onload="bindButtons();">`, use `window.onload = bindButtons;` in Javascript. Should accomplish the same thing, but separate HTML and JS more definitely

Answer (score 2):

If the user presses cancel then you need to stop the event from doing what it would normally do.  Try this, for example:

```
function delconfirm(e) {
    e = e || window.event;

    if (!confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this content?")) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // This will prevent the event from bubbling up to the <a>.
        e.stopPropagation();

        return false; // For the ancient/crappy browsers still out there.
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: In order for any of the `return`ing to work, that means the button would need `return` as well - `onclick="return delconfirm();"`

Comment: @Ian Right. Thankfully, the two method invocations on the event object *should* be sufficient for any modern browser.

Comment: Haha exactly...hopefully they're enough :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop/delete the current click event. After your code is executed the event sinks to the anchor and triggers a click. With MooTools just add 'new Event().stop();'. I think jQuery has also something like this.

EDIT: Hanlet Escaño is right. You can return true (the browser will redirect to the URL in the href, or false to let the browser do nothing)

Comment: "*sinks*"? The right term is "event *bubbling*", and the click was already triggered

Answer (score 1):

In order to prevent to the HTML link to work, you have to return false in your js function or event.preventDefault() where event is an argument which is passed to the click event function

I did thin when putting a click event on the a element and not on an element inside the a tag. But it might work.